# Can't access ansible_host property of my inventory items

Tags: ansible

I have this inventory file:

```
[masters]
master ansible_host=1.2.3.4.5 ansible_user=ubuntu

[workers]
worker1 ansible_host=1.2.3.4.5 ansible_user=ubuntu

[nodes]
master ansible_host=1.2.3.4.5 ansible_user=ubuntu
worker1 ansible_host=1.2.3.4.5 ansible_user=ubuntu

[fileserver]
fs-01 ansible_host=1.2.3.4.5 ansible_user=ubuntu
```

I'm trying to install an SSH key from my local machine to all inventory machines.

```
- name: install the SSH key on all machines.
  hosts: 127.0.0.1
  connection: local
  tasks:
  - name: install SSH-key 
    shell: sshpass -p {{ ssh_key_password }} ssh-copy-id -i /id_rsa.pub -o StrictHostKeyChecking ubuntu@{{ item }}
    with_items:
      - "{{ hostvars['all'].ansible_host }}"
```

However, it ends with this error:

```
fatal: [127.0.0.1]: FAILED! => {"msg": "\"hostvars['all']\" is undefined"}
```

I'm trying to get the ansible_host `1.2.3.4.5` of each unique inventory name in my inventory. However, I'm not having much luck. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going about it backward.  Ansible automatically loops through your play hosts, so use your hosts, not `localhost`, then delegate the task to `localhost`.

```
- name: install the SSH key on all machines.
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - name: install SSH-key 
    shell: sshpass -p {{ ssh_key_password }} ssh-copy-id -i /id_rsa.pub -o StrictHostKeyChecking {{ ansible_user }}@{{ ansible_host }}
    delegate_to: localhost
```

Answer (score 0):

`hostvars` is a dictionary that stores the ansible hosts as keys and their variables as values. so for your inventory, the `hostvars` dict would look like this:

```
master: {...}
worker1: {...}
fs-01: {...}
```

The reason `all` returns undefined is because you don't have a host named `all`.

Since you just want the hostname, instead of `hostvars['all'].ansible_host`, just use `ansible_host` which will resolve the hostname for you to ssh into.

Like so:

```
    with_items:
      - "{{ ansible_host }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the referencing you are looking for is something as below

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - name: Print all hosts
    debug:
     msg: "{{hostvars[item]['ansible_host']}}"
    with_items:
    - "{{groups['all']}}"
```

This gives the output

```
PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Print all hosts] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=master) => {
    "msg": "1.2.3.4.5"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=worker1) => {
    "msg": "1.2.3.4.5"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=fs-01) => {
    "msg": "1.2.3.4.5"
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```